# QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected on Windows in Debug without creation of new threads

Tags: c++, qt

The following code sometimes failes on Windows x64 in **DEBUG**: I close the `_mainView` and see the empty **white** form of `_loginView` and then the program just crashes with `QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected` message. **I do not create any threads myself in my application.**

```cpp
void GuiLauncher::handleOnLogin()
{
    _loginView->hide();
    _loginView.reset();

    _mainView.reset(new MainView{});

    CONNECT(*_mainView, onLogout(), *this, handleOnLogout());

    _mainView->show();
}

void GuiLauncher::handleOnLogout()
{
    _mainView->hide();
    _mainView.reset();

    _loginView.reset(new LoginView{});

    CONNECT(*_loginView, onLogin(), *this, handleOnLogin());

    _loginView->show();
}
```

In debugger in vscode I get:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Qt\5.12.12\msvc2017_64\bin\Qt5Widgetsd.dll
File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector
Line: 208

Expression: vector iterator range transposed

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application)
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\TextShaping.dll'. 
Second Chance Assertion Failed: File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\vector, Line 208
```

Is anything wrong with my code at the first glance? Thank  you for attention.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the crash (**on Windows in DEBUG mode**) is due the fact that auto-generated ui file contained:

```
       <widget class="QToolButton" name="button_logout">
       </widget>
```

which would generate the code

```cpp
        QToolButton *button_logout;
        button_logout = new QToolButton(widget_session_list);
        button_logout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("button_logout"));
        header_layout->addWidget(button_logout);
```

So having a clicked event due to this connection:

```cpp
...
    connect(_ui->button_logout, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &ViewImpl::performLogout);
...

void ViewImpl::performLogout()
{
    emit onLogout();
}
```

led to the crash after the window would be `hidden` and `deleted` as a reaction on the signal `onLogout()`.

So I have asked the next question: [QToolButton crashes on clicked and window initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71061984/4781940).