# QToolButton crashes on clicked and window destruction

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, debugging, qt5

I have asked the question [QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected on Windows in Debug without creation of new threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71048401/4781940). It turned out that the crash (**on Windows in DEBUG mode**) is due the fact that auto-generated ui file contained:

```
       <widget class="QToolButton" name="button_logout">
       </widget>
```

which would generate the code

```cpp
        QToolButton *button_logout;
        button_logout = new QToolButton(widget_session_list);
        button_logout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("button_logout"));
        header_layout->addWidget(button_logout);
```

So having a clicked event due to this connection:

```cpp
...
    connect(_ui->button_logout, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &ViewImpl::performLogout);
...

void ViewImpl::performLogout()
{
    emit onLogout();
}
```

led to the crash with  `QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected` after the window would be `hidden` and `deleted` as a reaction on the signal `onLogout()`.

---

However, I discovered that if I replace the `QToolButton` with `QPushButton` I do not get the crash and everything is fixed.

So my question is why? What is wrong with the `QToolButton`? And why is the problem on Windows in Debug mode and I do not have it on Linux or on Window in Release mode. Honestly, I have already encountered strange crashes on Windows in Debug mode for Qt. E.g., I remember once that `QVariantList` failed there, so I got rid of it. I must note here that I build against debug qt libraries and tried `\MT`, `\MDd`, and `\MTd` runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your shutdown / logout logic is flawed: I guess, that you delete the object from which you are running your logout code. Try to replace the call to `delete()` with
`deleteLater()` and see what happens. For further diagnosis, we'd need more information about your object tree, construction and destruction.

It has absolutely nothing to do with the kind of button you are using, that is absolutely accidental.

Comment: I have shown how I create and destroy the views here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71048401/4781940

Comment: I would appreciate your  comment on how you find those creations/destructions.